# Bot Discord Python - Update channel name in a background loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm developping a little Discord Bot and I'm stuck on something.

To update a channe name, I need the **bot context**.

But on my background task, there is no context at all, so I can't figure it out how to achieve what I need.
So the code above cannot work because of the line 23, where ctx doesn't exist

> selectedVcChannel = discord.utils.get(**ctx**.guild.channels, name=VcChannelName)

I tried to make the ctx variable global, and tried to put the channel in a variable, but after changing the first time the name, the second time doesn't work anymore. That's why I'm trying to get it in all loops with `discord.utils.get`.

(VcChannelName is set in another function not showed here, don't worry about it).

```
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

selectedVcChannel = None
VcChannelName = None

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

# Background task
async def background_task():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

    while not bot.is_closed():
        await call_api()
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

# Call of the web page and update channel name
async def call_api():
    global selectedVcChannel
    global VcChannelName

    if VcChannelName:
        selectedVcChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=VcChannelName)
        response = requests.get('https://MyAPI')
        respDecoded = response.content.decode("utf-8")
        VcChannelName = TranslationChannelName + respDecoded
        await selectedVcChannel.edit(name=VcChannelName)

# Start bot
bot.loop.create_task(background_task())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

How can I use the context commands in the background loop easily ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this, to loop through the guilds your bot is a member of with `bot.guilds` and call `discord.utils.get` on each guild's channels. Altough using `id` instead of `name` would probably be better. You can keep the ids in a database maybe.

You can't get [context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) in a background task because it is something exclusive to the bot commands.

```
if VcChannelName:
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        # if you want to find the channel by id
        # selectedVcChannel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, id=voice_channel_id)
        selectedVcChannel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=VcChannelName)
        # If you want the first channel found with the name of 'VcChannelName' 
        # you can add this condition with a break statement,
        # you obviously don't need this if you use id
        if selectedVcChannel:
           break

    if selectedVcChannel:
        response = requests.get('https://MyAPI')
        respDecoded = response.content.decode("utf-8")
        VcChannelName = TranslationChannelName + respDecoded
        await selectedVcChannel.edit(name=VcChannelName)
```

Comment: Thanks ! What is the good way to do it then ? Do I need to make my bot create the channel, store the id and use it to rename it in my loop ? Because today I'm using only a command which setup the name and that's not very convinient

Comment: @CallMeAudric You need to explain what you want to do exactly. In your question you only asked how you could update channel names without context. If you want to update a specific channel you need to use its id which you can store in a database. If you use my answer as is, you might update the name of a different channel with the same name in a different guild.

Comment: @CallMeAudric I've edited my answer. If you want to use ids you can send the id as the second parameter in `discord.utils.get()` instead of name.

Comment: I don't want to abuse of your help, I will find it by myself. You answered the initial question, thanks